# Как самому написать функцию для создания окна?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Как самому написать функции создания окна в C++ без использования библиотек `windows.h`, `winAPI`. Как вообще это происходит?
Например я хочу создать свой 2д движок на чистом C++ без создания окна и отрисовки сторонними библиотеками, а сделать абсолютно всё с нуля, что для этого нужно? Возможно ли это вообще, или же без этих библиотек никак?

Comment: Вообще-то окна создает именно операционная система. Более того, C++ вообще ничего не знает об окнах или графике вообще... Это разве что в DOS в режиме VGA 320x200 можно было программировать вообще без ничего, напрямую с видеопамятью работая. Да и то для перехода в этот режим надо было прерывание дернуть — а это уже вне стандарта C++...

Comment: Я в этом не разбираюсь ,мне интересно,как именно устроенна библиотека windows.h знаю лишь,что она сама состоит из многих библиотек ,библиотека что позволяет создавать окно приложения это winAPI ,но как устроенна она,или хотя бы какие то кусочки опен сурса этой библиотеки не нашел,хочу узнать что происходит в самом низу систему если углубиться в во все эти библиотеки,и возможно ли написать такую же самому.

Comment: Да запросто — просто пишете свою операционную систему :) Опять же, самый низ — это где? Уровень API, уровень работы с железом или какой-то из промежуточных? Окно — это не не только вывод на экран, это еще и, например, встроиться в очередь сообщений — от клавиатуры, мыши и т.д. Только вот Windows — не open source, ее исходники спрятаны. Да и вряд ли вы через них прокопались бы, там даже не знаю, какие миллионы строк... Можете взглянуть на какой-нибудь из Linux'ов, эти есть в исходниках. Только вот чтоб самому такое написать, надо много лет, даже при наличии всех знаний...

Comment: Без WinAPI вы ничего не сделаете. Это минимальный уровень интерфейса, через который можно сделать оконное приложение Windows. Вам нужна функция [WinMain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain) для запуска приложения, функции доступа к event loop [GetMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage), [DispatchMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage), [PostMessage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea)

Comment: Плюс различные функции рисования, такие как [FillRect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-fillrect) и [DrawText](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext). Или же вы хотите самостоятельно реализовать оконные функции из User32.dll?

Comment: Верно как реализовать функции из User32.dll ,возможно ли сделать это в языке C++

Comment: В проекте Wine сделали альтернативные реализации всех основных DLL Windows, в том числе [User32.dll](https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/). Написано на Си, если считаете нужным - перепишите на С++. Но как всегда есть одно НО. В Wine вместо системных функций Windows из kernel.dll используется вызов сервера Wine.

Comment: И ещё мысль. Когда решитесь своими руками переписать WinAPI, прочтите для начала хотя бы первый том [Windows Internals](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-internals-seventh/9780133986471/).

Comment: @PakUula Wine на линуксе наверняка сам использует X11/Wayland. Как он без них смог бы создать окна...

Comment: windows.h ,winAPI,  -  не закрытые библиотеки а часть ОС. ПОд практически любой  современной ОС Вам придется  написать свой драйвер работы с оборудованием (и подписать его у производителей)  чтобы "сдать все самому". В Линукс есть "фальшивый" прямой доступ к видеопамяти, тоже обеспечиваемый ядром и драйвером для оборудования.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat или фреймбуфер, но они все равно используют функции ОС. ОП какбы категорически не хочет... следовательно ему нужно писать свою ось

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вопрос в том, насколько глубоко топикстартер готов погрузиться. Рисование окошек и контролов в конечном итоге сводится к вызовам WinGDI API. Как ими пользоваться - можно посмотреть в Wine. Но только рисовать окошки - это не приложение. Приложение обязано обрабатывать сообщения event loop-а. А как это сделано в Wnidows - бог весть. В Wine точно сделано по-другому.

Answer (score 3):

Сомневаюсь, что на Windows можно опуститься ниже уровня WinAPI.

На линуксе есть [linux framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer) - можно рисовать напрямую на экран, без окон и т. п.

---

Кроме того, если не хотите, чтобы ваш "движок" работал быстро, нужно рисовать на GPU, а не на CPU. Для этого придется использовать одно из API, предоставляемых драйверами видеокарт - OpenGL, Vulkan, ... Свою замену для них вы сделать не сможете, ведь для этого нужно написать свой драйвер и убедить игроков поставить его.

---

Если хотите мое мнение: вы только потратите время впустую.

Вам хватит проблем с движком и без самодельной графики.

Лучше возьмите **кросс-платформенную** графическую библиотеку, например [SDL2](http://libsdl.org/). Она достаточно низкоуровневая, чтобы не было скучно, и при этом работает на всех крупных ОС.

Comment: "Кроме того, если не хотите, чтобы ваш "движок" безбожно тормозил, нужно рисовать на GPU, а не на CPU. " - да да, не менее двух nvidia 3080/3090. Да можно и на обычном процессоре. Все же зависит от размаха.

Comment: В Windows для этого есть GDI API.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, если ты готов написать порядка 100.000 строк хардкорного кода самостоятельно, притом часть из него будет на ассемблере, потому что многие действия связанные с системным программированием просто нельзя написать иначе.